# Passing jobs to another function without delay arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to read rotary encoder input and press a joystick button for every increment. The button press needs to be at least 3ms to register with Windows, but that delay will stop the encoder from processing new information. I've read through the BlinkWithoutDelay questions, but that's not what I need.

I want to pass the button press off to another function so the rotary encoder can continue. How can I run the button press function and force the encoder to continue without waiting?

Sorry if this was a bit confusing

```
#include <Joystick.h>
#include <ClickEncoder.h>

Joystick_ Joystick;

int counter = 0; 
int aState;
int aLastState; 

#define outputA 5
#define outputB 6

void setup() {
    Joystick.begin();
    Serial.begin (9600);
    pinMode (outputA,INPUT);
    pinMode (outputB,INPUT);
    aLastState = digitalRead(outputA);
}

void loop() {
    aState = digitalRead(outputA);
    if ((aLastState == HIGH) && (aState == LOW)) {
      if (digitalRead(outputB) == LOW) {
        Joystick.setButton(1, 1);
        delay(5);
        Joystick.setButton(1, 0);
        counter ++;
      } else {
        Joystick.setButton(1, 1);
        delay(5);
        Joystick.setButton(1, 0);
        counter --;
      }
      Serial.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Contrary to what you think, Blink Without Delay is *exactly* what you need.  Start your joystick and record the time.  Don’t wait for 3ms, just record the time and exit   The loop function keeps running.  You don’t need to pass the job anywhere, just let loop keep looping and constantly checking against that time.  When it’s been three milliseconds loop will have gone round hundreds or even thousands of times since it started with the joystick.  Once it sees 3ms is up stop with the joystick.

Comment: Could you send a snippet of code or clarify that a bit? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: What part don't you understand?  What part do you understand?  "I don't understand" is such a useless statement on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

This is uncompiled and untested and may contain typos, but should give you the picture.

I wasn't sure what you wanted to do with clicks on the encoder while the button was pressed.  I chose to count them but not to have another press for them.  That isn't important.  You should be able to fix that if this isn't exactly what you want.  Either way, see how I use the buttonPressed and pressStarted variables to track the state of the joystick button and let the loop keep looping and checking the time instead of sitting dead waiting for it to pass.

```
unsigned long pressStarted;
boolean buttonPressed = false;  // to keep track of whether we're pressing the joystick button or not.

void loop() {
  if (buttonPressed && (millis() - pressStarted >= 3)) {
    Joystick.setButton(1, 0);
    buttonPressed = false;
  }
  aState = digitalRead(outputA);
  if ((aLastState == HIGH) && (aState == LOW)) {
    if (digitalRead(outputB) == LOW) {
      if (!buttonPressed) {
        Joystick.setButton(1, 1);
        pressStarted = millis();
        buttonPressed = true;
      }
      counter ++;
    } else {
      if (!buttonPressed) {
        Joystick.setButton(1, 1);
        pressStarted = millis();
        buttonPressed = true;
      }
      counter --;
    }
    Serial.println(counter);
  }
}
```

Comment: That code didn't quite work, but I understand the concept now, thanks.

Comment: That could should work.  It may not do exactly what YOU wanted, but since you haven't yet made that clear to anyone else I'm not sure what you expected.  But the code as written will press the button if it isn't already pressed and the encoder clicks and will keep counting clicks while it is holding the button.